# How to send SQL count data & array data together?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script designed to print out values of students who have accrued more than 3 tardies.  I want this script to print out both the student name, and the amount of times they've been tardy, but so far I've been only able to print out their names with the following script:

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT StudentID,classid,date from attendance_main where status = 'Tardy' AND classid like '%ADV%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $studentid = $row['StudentID'];
        $sql2 = "select distinct StudentID,classid,date from attendance_main where StudentID = '$studentid' AND status = 'Tardy' AND classid like '%ADV%'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());
        while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
                $tardycount = mysql_num_rows($result2);
                $studentid = $row2['StudentID'];
                if($tardycount >= 3) {

                                $sql3 = "select * from students where rfid = '$studentid'";
                                $result3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die (mysql_error());
                                while($row3=mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
                                        $fname[] = $row3['fname'];
                                }
                        }
                }
        }


$newdata = array_unique($fname);
foreach ($newdata as $value) {
        echo $value;
}
```

I can't think of how to intuitively do this.  Keeping it all in the while loop didn't work (I had multiple results coming up for the same students despite requesting unique entries) so using array_unique was the only method I could think of.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add your table layout. On first glance your php script solution looks like its way too complicated if you really just want to print out student name and the amount of times they've been tardy. If this is the reason, it should be easily accomplishable in one single SQL statement, which you then can process with php to whatever needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) do almost everything in SQL. It should look something like this.

```
select StudentID, classid, date count(*)
from attendance_main
where status = 'Tardy' AND classid like '%ADV%'"
left join student on student.rfid = attendance_main.StudentId
group by StudentId
having count(*) > 3;
```

Here's how it works.

1. select the results you want to work with:

   select StudentID, classid, date count(*)
   from attendance_main 
   where status = 'Tardy' AND classid like '%ADV%'"
2. Join the students to your result set on the common id

   left join student on student.rfid = attendance_main.StudentId
3. group everything by student.  We use count(*) to get the number of items. We know we're only dealing with tardies because of the where clause in the select.

   group by StudentId
4. limit the results to only tardies above 3 with the having claues (this is like a where clause for the group by)

   having count(*) > 3;

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  attendance_main.StudentID, 
  students.fname,
  COUNT(attendance_main.*) AS `times_tardy` 
FROM 
  attendance_main  
INNER JOIN
  students 
ON
  attendance_main.StudentID = students.rfid
WHERE 
  attendance_main.status = 'Tardy' 
AND 
  attendance_main.classid like '%ADV%'
GROUP BY
  attendance_main.StudentID
HAVING
  `times_tardy` > 3
```

Joining the two tables gets you the tardy count and student's name in one query, and the GROUP BY and HAVING clause that get you only the students with more than 3 tardy entries.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm still relatively new to SQL queries, and I ran into the following problem:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS `times_tardy` FROM attendance_main t1 INNER JOIN students t2 ON t' at line 4

Am I being dumb, or was there a typo somewhere in that?

Comment: Try just COUNT(*) there, it's possible I've made mistakes as I didn't create tables to test the query on.

Comment: Thank you so much Dan. I hope one day it's this simple for me! Haha.